# dividing and multiplying by variables. What goes wrong?

Tags: inequality

1) x = x^-1
x = 1/x

Is this the same as x^2 = 1? Can you multiply both sides by X problem free? Does this problem only come up in inequalities?

2) x = x^-2
x=1/x^2
x^3=1

Is the above right?

3) x > x^2
1 > x if x>0
-1 < x if x<0

So does multiplying over X only occur with inequalities?

Comment: all are correct. the Q-- last line vague/not making sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply or divide equalities by x as long as you make sure that x is not 0. This is the case in your examples.

But the last one is wrong: For example, $-\frac 12$ is not greater than $(-\frac12)^2$. It must be $1 < x$ if $x < 0$, which of course cannot be true.